# How do I apply mosfet switching to this battery circuit

Tags: batteries, mosfet, power-electronics, switching

I have this circuit:

[image: lowside switch]

The circuit consists of a charging voltage (C+=42V,C-=0V), ~42V battery(B+=42V,C-=0V), and a low side mosfet switching circuit with an output P. When SW1 is connecting C and B, there is 42V across P, and when SW1 is connecting A and B, there is 0V across P.

What I would like help with is the following.

I want this circuit to operate such that when the charging voltage is connected across the battery, the circuit is put into a state where there is 0V across P, regardless of the state of SW1.

I think I would use a mosfet switch in series with R1 and SW1-C that opens when C is applied and closes when C is removed, and another mosfet switch in parallel with SW1-A and SW1-B that closes when C is applied and opens when C is removed.

I have tried various combinations of P and N mosfet switching circuits in LT spice, however I cannot get it to work how I would expect.

Does anyone have any suggestions of a way to achieve this using mosfet switch circuits?

Comment: If you stop switching SW1 then C1 will stop passing current and the voltage between P+ and P- will fall to zero. I can't see why you require any further switching.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The goal is that when the charger is connected, regardless of the state of SW1, there is 0V across P. In the current circuit, if SW1 is connecting C and B, and the charging voltage is applied, there will be 42V across P. This is not what I want.

Comment: Search for MOSFET series switches. or High side "smart" switches.

Comment: @makepeace: But C1 is in series. How can you have any voltage at P?

Comment: @Transistor Apologies, I transcribed my circuit incorrectly. It's fixed now.